# Stepper form throws issue with ngmodel

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to send the `form` persisted data to backend `API` (I have bound the `json` data to this `form` and trying to send to backend `API`) and I have created a `form` like this below (HTML / Template code is shown below). When I'm coming from one `form` to this particular `form` (the `form` which I am talking here) then it gives me some strange error messages in the console.

The error:

```
> ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name
> attribute must be set or the form
>       control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.
> 
>       Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
>       Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
```

For this i have added [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" to the form. But still i am getting the errors.

```
<mat-card>
    <section class="container-fluid with-maxwidth chapter">
        <article class="article1">            

            <div class="box1211 box-default12">
                <div class="box-body1">

                    <div class="box-body">

                        <form>        
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-0 control-label"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">

                                <mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]="project.genPolicy" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">Auto-Code Options
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <mat-radio-button class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let gen of genPolicies" color="primary" [value]="gen" [checked]="gen === 'Create'">
                                        {{gen}}
                                    </mat-radio-button>
                                </mat-radio-group>

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <div class="callout1 text-muted callout-info1">
                                    <p>Auto-Code (automatic test coverage for your APIs).
                                        <br/>Continuously generates 5-point test coverage (Quality, Security, DOS, Injections,
                                        Data-Leak, Log-forging etc) for all project endpoints.
                                        <br/>Requires repository credentials for code check-in.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row" *ngIf="project.genPolicy === 'Create'">
                            <div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let res of autoCodeConfig">
                                <div *ngIf='res.type === "anonymous_invalid"'>
                                    <mat-accordion>
                                        <mat-expansion-panel>
                                            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                                <mat-panel-title>
                                                    <b>Type - {{ res.type }}</b>
                                                </mat-panel-title>
                                            </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                                            <mat-form-field>
                                                <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions" [(ngModel)]='res.assertions' rows="3" cols="150" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></textarea>
                                            </mat-form-field>
                                            <br/>
                                            <label>Severity</label>
                                            <mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]='res.severity' [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                                                <mat-radio-button color="primary" class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let sev of severity" [value]="sev">
                                                    {{sev}}
                                                </mat-radio-button>
                                            </mat-radio-group>

                                        </mat-expansion-panel>
                                    </mat-accordion>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let res of autoCodeConfig">
                                <div *ngIf='res.type === "auth_invalid"'>
                                    <mat-accordion>
                                        <mat-expansion-panel>
                                            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                                                <mat-panel-title>
                                                    <b>Type - {{ res.type }}</b>
                                                </mat-panel-title>
                                            </mat-expansion-panel-header>

                                            <mat-form-field>
                                                <textarea matInput placeholder="Assertions" [(ngModel)]='res.assertions' [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></textarea>
                                            </mat-form-field>
                                            <br/>
                                            <label>Severity</label>
                                            <mat-radio-group class="example-radio-group" [(ngModel)]='res.severity' [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                                                <mat-radio-button color="primary" class="example-radio-button" *ngFor="let sev of severity" [value]="sev">
                                                    {{sev}}
                                                </mat-radio-button>
                                            </mat-radio-group>

                                        </mat-expansion-panel>
                                    </mat-accordion>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <mat-card-actions>
                            <button color="primary" mat-raised-button matStepperNext class="nav-btn pull-right">Save & Next</button>
                        </mat-card-actions>

                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>

    </section>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Why are you even using form tags, since you are not utilizing it for an angular form?

Comment: @AJT_82 it adds some styling/grouping by default, plus it makes the code easier to read

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Sure, I understand that. I was rather subtly (unrelated) trying to nudge OP to utilizing angular forms :D

Comment: @ AJT_82: Can we send all form data to backenn api without using form also? Please suggest..